# Disable a caret (^) character in JavaScript using RegEx

Tags: javascript, html, regex, caret

I am trying to create a "Register" form, where people can sign-up to use the service by providing their information such as First Name. I have created a regular expression, which I thought would exclude any character different than A-Z and . - ' symbols. The functionality has been achieved and users can't type in most special character in the First name field, except the caret (`^`) symbol. Could you please help me  to modify my regex, so that it doesn't allow the users to type in a caret symbol? I have tried adding something like `^\^` and `^\\^`, but these did not work.

EDIT: I found a way to achieve this, I just added another line of code to the validate method that takes care purely of replacing the caret symbol. Thanks for your help!

```js
function validateInputFields(f) {
    !(/^[A-z ,.'-]+$/i).test(f.value) ? f.value = f.value.replace(/[^A-z,.'-]/ig, '') : null;
   f.value = f.value.replace(/\^/g, "");
}
```

```html
<input tabindex=3 name="txtFirstName" type="text" id="txtFirstName" 
       onkeyup="validateInputFields(this)" 
       onblur="validateInputFields(this)">
```

Comment: Remove the ^ in your regex

Comment: That did not work, as I wanted to allow characters between A-Z. Anyway I found a way and I will edit the post now.

Comment: @user3036342 In the regex here it means "beginning of string".

Comment: @speed-e If you have an answer, don't edit the question--create an answer.

Comment: Also `[A-z]` matches a couple of non-letters.

Comment: Consider fixing your regular expression (which is also letting `[`, `]` and some others through) rather than correcting for one specific failure after the fact. See my answer below.

Comment: Downvoting since the edited "solution" is pathological and a terrible example (all the more so given that an actual solution is a two-character edit).

Answer (score 3):

You're including the range `A-z`, which includes all uppercase letters, all lowercase letters, and the characters in between those - including `^`. Selecting *just* the alphabet will do the job:

```js
 function validateInputFields(f) 
    {
      !(/^[A-Z ,.'-]+$/i).test(f.value) ? f.value = f.value.replace(/[^A-Z,.'-]/ig, '') : null;
    }
```